# Merging 2 non overlapping points datasets

Tags: r, point, merge

I have 2 dataset of points, each one measures a different variable, i need to "merge"(not sure if it is the correct term) these two into one dataset.

My first instinct is to take a purple point find k closets green points and assign the average as the green dataset value for the purple point.

Example image of the points.

[image]

Is there a recommend method for this kind of problem?

Edit:

I am using R, but if there is not package that solves the problem i will be fine with a theoretical reference.

Edit 2:

Added code to generate an example, i would like a to know which methods are available and which ones are recommended for a case like this.

```
library(sf)


N_points <-  100
X_range <- c(0, 20)
Y_range <- c(0, 20)

set.seed(123)
df_1 <- data.frame(
x = truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n = N_points,  a=X_range[1], b=X_range[2], mean=10, sd=5),
y = truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n = N_points,  a=Y_range[1], b=Y_range[2], mean=10, sd=5),
value = rnorm(n = N_points, mean=7, sd=2)
)  %>%  st_as_sf(coords=c("x", "y"))


set.seed(753)
df_2 <- data.frame(
x = truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n = N_points,  a=X_range[1], b=X_range[2], mean=10, sd=5),
y = truncnorm::rtruncnorm(n = N_points,  a=Y_range[1], b=Y_range[2], mean=10, sd=5),
value = rnorm(n = N_points, mean=10, sd=2)
)  %>%  st_as_sf(coords=c("x", "y"))



plot(st_geometry(df_1), col="purple", axes = TRUE)
plot(st_geometry(df_2), col="green", add=T)
```

[image]

Edit 3, my description of the problem was not clear enough:

Example:

Each purple point represent a measure of air pollution.

Each green point represent a measure of radiation.

I want as result a datasets that has both a measure of radiation and a measure of air pollution for each point.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  If your question is theoretical then please make that clear and tag it  with the [tag:gis-principle] tag.

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation of that "k nearest neighbours + averaging" thing specifically, or do you want a more general discussion of how to relate two point data sets? It would help if you could supply some data or show some code to generate a simple test data set so we can all work on it.

Comment: I'm not sure what class of general problem you are trying to solve. Taking the k-nearest and averaging is one thing, it does what it does. Quite what it means in terms of your underlying problem I don't know. What's the big question? How do these two sets of points relate in the real world?

Comment: @Spacedman, i never had this problem before so i am not sure if that is a good idea or there is "recommended way" to do it.

Comment: What I don't understand is what your problem is. You have two measurements of **different variables** and want to combine them into a single set of measurements of something? What's that "something" going to be? Suppose the first measurement is percentage of gold in a soil sample, and the second is percentage of silver - how does it make sense to merge them?

Comment: @Spacedman, i edited the question hoping that is clear enough, if that is not case please let me know.

Comment: Ah ha! You could use **kriging** to generate two smooth surface models for your quantities and then generate predictions for variable A using the model for B and vice versa, or (possibly) use cokriging which (I think) could generate a multivariate surface model for both variables simultaneously. You also get error estimates of the predictions.

Comment: @Spacedman, i will test it and add result.